# What is the best way to save JNIEnv*

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jnienv

I have an Android project with JNI. In the CPP file which implements a listener class, there is a callback x() . When x() function is called, I want to call another function in a java class. However, in order to invoke that java function, I need to access JNIEnv*.

I know that in the same cpp file of the callback, there is a function:

```
static jboolean init (JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {...}
```

Should I save in the cpp file JNIEnv* as member variable when `init(..)` is called? and use it later when the callback happens?

Sorry but I am a beginner in JNI.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Caching a `JNIEnv*` is not a particularly good idea, since you can't use the same `JNIEnv*` across multiple threads, and might not even be able to use it for multiple native calls on the same thread (see http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html)

Writing a function that gets the `JNIEnv*` and attaches the current thread to the VM if necessary isn't too difficult:

```
bool GetJniEnv(JavaVM *vm, JNIEnv **env) {
    bool did_attach_thread = false;
    *env = nullptr;
    // Check if the current thread is attached to the VM
    auto get_env_result = vm->GetEnv((void**)env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    if (get_env_result == JNI_EDETACHED) {
        if (vm->AttachCurrentThread(env, NULL) == JNI_OK) {
            did_attach_thread = true;
        } else {
            // Failed to attach thread. Throw an exception if you want to.
        }
    } else if (get_env_result == JNI_EVERSION) {
        // Unsupported JNI version. Throw an exception if you want to.
    }
    return did_attach_thread;
}
```

The way you'd use it is:

```
JNIEnv *env;
bool did_attach = GetJniEnv(vm, &env);
// Use env...
// ...
if (did_attach) {
   vm->DetachCurrentThread();
}
```

You could wrap this in a class that attaches upon construction and detaches upon destruction, RAII-style:

```
class ScopedEnv {
public:
    ScopedEnv() : attached_to_vm_(false) {
        attached_to_vm_ = GetJniEnv(g_vm, &env_);  // g_vm is a global
    }

    ScopedEnv(const ScopedEnv&) = delete;
    ScopedEnv& operator=(const ScopedEnv&) = delete;

    virtual ~ScopedEnv() {
        if (attached_to_vm_) {
            g_vm->DetachCurrentThread();
            attached_to_vm_ = false;
        }
    }

    JNIEnv *GetEnv() const { return env_; }

private:
    bool attached_to_env_;
    JNIEnv *env_;
};

// Usage:

{
    ScopedEnv scoped_env;
    scoped_env.GetEnv()->SomeJniFunction();
}
// scoped_env falls out of scope, the thread is automatically detached if necessary
```

---

**Edit:** Sometimes you might have a long-ish running native thread that will need a `JNIEnv*` on multiple occasions. In such situations you may want to avoid constantly attaching and detaching the thread to/from the JVM, but you still need to make sure that you detach the thread upon thread destruction.

You can accomplish this by attaching the thread only once and then leaving it attached, and by setting up a thread destruction callback using `pthread_key_create` and `pthread_setspecific` that will take care of calling `DetachCurrentThread`.

```
/**
 * Get a JNIEnv* valid for this thread, regardless of whether
 * we're on a native thread or a Java thread.
 * If the calling thread is not currently attached to the JVM
 * it will be attached, and then automatically detached when the
 * thread is destroyed.
 */   
JNIEnv *GetJniEnv() {
    JNIEnv *env = nullptr;
    // We still call GetEnv first to detect if the thread already
    // is attached. This is done to avoid setting up a DetachCurrentThread
    // call on a Java thread.

    // g_vm is a global.
    auto get_env_result = g_vm->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    if (get_env_result == JNI_EDETACHED) {
        if (g_vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL) == JNI_OK) {
            DeferThreadDetach(env);
        } else {
            // Failed to attach thread. Throw an exception if you want to.
        }
    } else if (get_env_result == JNI_EVERSION) {
        // Unsupported JNI version. Throw an exception if you want to.
    }
    return env;
}

void DeferThreadDetach(JNIEnv *env) {
    static pthread_key_t thread_key;

    // Set up a Thread Specific Data key, and a callback that
    // will be executed when a thread is destroyed.
    // This is only done once, across all threads, and the value
    // associated with the key for any given thread will initially
    // be NULL.
    static auto run_once = [] {
        const auto err = pthread_key_create(&thread_key, [] (void *ts_env) {
            if (ts_env) {
                g_vm->DetachCurrentThread();
            }
        });
        if (err) {
            // Failed to create TSD key. Throw an exception if you want to.
        }
        return 0;
    }();

    // For the callback to actually be executed when a thread exits
    // we need to associate a non-NULL value with the key on that thread.
    // We can use the JNIEnv* as that value.
    const auto ts_env = pthread_getspecific(thread_key);
    if (!ts_env) {
        if (pthread_setspecific(thread_key, env)) {
            // Failed to set thread-specific value for key. Throw an exception if you want to.
        }
    }
}
```

If `__cxa_thread_atexit` is available to you, you might be able to accomplish the same thing with some `thread_local` object that calls `DetachCurrentThread` in its destructor.

Comment: Hi @Michael, thanks for the neat way to automatically detach threads on exit using TLS — it is also useful to detach threads that your code does not own (e.g., some framework threads).

Comment: > Caching a JNIEnv* is not a particularly good idea, [...] _and might not even be able to use it for multiple native calls on the same thread_ 
— I don't see that the linked article suggest that JNI interface pointer might change for a given thread. The [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jni/design.html#jni-interface-functions-and-pointers) says that "The VM is guaranteed to pass the same interface pointer to a native method when it makes multiple calls to the native method from the same Java thread". I don't think it is different for Invocation API.

Comment: @DmitryTimofeev: _"I don't see that the linked article suggest that JNI interface pointer might change for a given thread"_. That referred to Google's phrasing _"They **might be** valid if the next native call happens on the same thread"_, i.e. their choice of "might be" rather than "will be".

Comment: Got it, thanks! It would be strange though if their implementation did not conform to the specification. 
Anyway, it is definitely more reliable to just use `JavaVM#GetEnv` (if the code expects the thread to be attached) or `JavaVM#AttachCurrentThread` to obtain a valid pointer.

Comment: Actually, when I think about it, I can't make sense of this phrasing — if the JNIEnv is obtained via `AttachCurrentThread` (JNIEnv is its *output* parameter), then the only reasonable expectation of the caller is that they can use it — in the same thread — for as long as it remains attached (i.e., until this thread calls `DetachCurrentThread`).

Comment: Millions of thanks for this!!

Answer (score 2):

@Michael, gives a good overview of how best to retrieve the JNI by caching the JVM.
For those that dont want to use pthread (or cant' because you are on Windows system), and you are using c++ 11 or highter, then thread_local storage is the way to go.

Bellow is rough example on how to implement a wrapper method that properly attaches to a thread and automatically cleans-up when the thread exits

```
JNIEnv* JNIThreadHelper::GetJniEnv() {

    // This method might have been called from a different thread than the one that created
    // this handler. Check to make sure that the JNI is attached and if not attach it to the 
    // new thread.

    // double check it's all ok
    int nEnvStat = m_pJvm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_pJniEnv), JNI_VERSION_1_6);

    if (nEnvStat == JNI_EDETACHED) {

        std::cout << "GetEnv: not attached. Attempting to attach" << std::endl;

        JavaVMAttachArgs args;
        args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; // choose your JNI version
        args.name = NULL; // you might want to give the java thread a name
        args.group = NULL; // you might want to assign the java thread to a ThreadGroup

        if (m_pJvm->AttachCurrentThread(&m_pJniEnv, &args) != 0) {
            std::cout << "Failed to attach" << std::endl;
            return nullptr;
        }

        thread_local struct DetachJniOnExit {
            ~DetachJniOnExit() {
                m_pJvm->DetachCurrentThread();
            }
        };


        m_bIsAttachedOnAThread = true;

    }
    else if (nEnvStat == JNI_OK) {
        //
    }
    else if (nEnvStat == JNI_EVERSION) {

        std::cout << "GetEnv: version not supported" << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }


    return m_pJniEnv;
}
```

Comment: Note that there is already an accepted answer to this question. Please [edit] your answer to ensure that it improves upon other answers already present in this question.