# Does JNI work properly when calling multi-threaded C++ code?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to decide if JNI is for our use case.

We have a library written in C++ that fetches data from Database/RPC using multiple threads, and we want to create a wrapper to let Java code be able to call it.

I'm not familiar with JNI, so I would like to know if C++ multithreading will still work properly in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I can't find an answer on the internet. If you want to close, mind help me refine the question?

Comment: Multiple native threads are not a problem. But you cannot share the same `JNIEnv*` across threads (see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026030/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-jnienv/30026231)).

Comment: Thanks Michael, we're not gonna do anything with the threads in Java code, just returning result.

Comment: In theory this works fine, however, I have run into quite a few issues in practice.  It is very hard to provide thread safety between native thread implementations and the JVM, and near impossible to debug resulting issues.  I would strongly recommend keeping the concurrency on one side or the other, and in my experience, keeping it on the java side is a bit easier.

Comment: @AlexBarker Thanks Alex. thread safety shouldn't be an issue for us, cause everything that get passed between C++ and Java code are some protobuf objects, there's no interaction across code other than that. So I guess in this case, it's ok to have concurrency on both side?

Comment: @laike9m Possibly? No way to say for sure until you try it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any major issues in neither direction. Unless you have something really specific.

Here you have sample that calls JNI code from multiple threads:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-024/

Here you have sample that calls Java from multiple C threads:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-no-027/