# C++ Callback to Java -> Why can't I retrieve JNIEnv in callback class when coming from a different thread?

Tags: android, c++, jvm, java-native-interface, jnienv

I'm trying to build a callback class to make a call to a Java method from different threads in my native code, on Android. I have read a lot about how to that, and as long as I'm on the same thread, it all works. But from a different thread I can't retrieve the `JNIEnv` properly, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm not very experienced with C++ and the JNI so it's quite possible this is some beginner's problem...but I've spetd days on it and can't see what it is.

This is my Callback class, .h and .cpp file:

```
class AudioCallback {

public:
   explicit AudioCallback(JavaVM&, jobject);
    void playBackProgress(int progressPercentage);

private:
    JavaVM& g_jvm;
    jobject g_object;
};
```

```
jclass target = NULL;
jmethodID id = NULL;

AudioCallback::AudioCallback(JavaVM &jvm, jobject object) : g_jvm(jvm), g_object(object) {
    JNIEnv *g_env;
    int getEnvStat = g_jvm.GetEnv((void **) &g_env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

    if (g_env != NULL) {
        target = g_env->GetObjectClass(g_object);
        id = g_env->GetMethodID(target, "integerCallback", "(I)V");

        //This is a test call to see if I can call my java method. It works.
        g_env->CallVoidMethod(g_object, id, (jint) 103);
    }
}

// this method is calles from other threads, so I want to attach to the current thread once I got my JNIEnv, but I can't since it's null...
void AudioCallback::playBackProgress(int progressPercentage) {
    JNIEnv *g_env;

    // This is null and I don't know why!
    int getEnvStat = g_jvm.GetEnv((void **) &g_env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);


    if (g_env == NULL) {
        LOGE("JNIEnv in callback method is null");
    } else {
        LOGD("Env Stat: %d", getEnvStat);
        JavaVMAttachArgs vmAttachArgs;
        if (getEnvStat == JNI_EDETACHED) {
            LOGD("GetEnv: not attached - attaching");
            if (g_jvm.AttachCurrentThread(&g_env, &vmAttachArgs) != 0) {
                LOGD("GetEnv: Failed to attach");
            }
        } else if (getEnvStat == JNI_OK) {
            LOGD("GetEnv: JNI_OK");
        } else if (getEnvStat == JNI_EVERSION) {
            LOGD("GetEnv: version not supported");
        }
        g_env->CallVoidMethod(g_object, id, (jint) progressPercentage);
        //thread gets detached elsewhere
    }
}
```

This is my native_lib, where I get the `JavaVM` and instantiate the callback class:

```
std::unique_ptr<AudioEngine> audioEngine;
std::unique_ptr<AudioCallback> callback;

JavaVM *g_jvm = nullptr;

static jobject myJNIClass;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *pJvm, void *reserved) {
    g_Jvm = pJvm;
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_my_appy_common_jni_JniBridge_playFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,jstring URI) {

    myJNIClass = env->NewGlobalRef(instance);

    callback = std::make_unique<AudioCallback>(*gJvm, myJNIClass);

    // this test call to my callback works
    callback->playBackProgress(104);

    const char *uri = env->GetStringUTFChars(URI, NULL);

    //... urelated code is left out here ...

    //audioEngine gets the callback and uses it from threads it creates
    audioEngine = std::make_unique<AudioEngine>(*extractor, *callback);
    audioEngine->setFileName(uri);
    audioEngine->start();
}
```

I've shortened the code and removed all unrelated/unnecessary parts. If something crucial is missing, please comment and I'll add it.

**Solution: As per the suggestions @Michael made in his answer, I made these edits to the `playbackProgress`method in my callback class to make it work:**

```
void AudioCallback::playBackProgress(int progressPercentage) {
    JNIEnv *g_env;
    int getEnvStat = g_jvm.GetEnv((void **) &g_env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

    if (getEnvStat == JNI_EDETACHED) {
        LOGD("GetEnv: not attached - attaching");
        if (g_jvm.AttachCurrentThread(&g_env, NULL) != 0) {
            LOGD("GetEnv: Failed to attach");
        }
    } else if (getEnvStat == JNI_OK) {
        LOGD("GetEnv: JNI_OK");
    } else if (getEnvStat == JNI_EVERSION) {
        LOGD("GetEnv: version not supported");
    }
    g_env->CallVoidMethod(g_object, id, (jint) progressPercentage);
//    mJvm.DetachCurrentThread();
}
```

Now it checks for the value of `getEnvStat` directly, the null check of `g_env` before was wrong. I also had to replace the `JavaVMAttachArgs`with `NULL`to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic in `playBackProgress` wrong.

The only time your try to attach the current thread is when `g_env` is non-NULL. But if `g_env` is non-NULL then `GetEnv` probably succeeded (you should of course also check that `getEnvStat == JNI_OK`) and `AttachCurrentThread` isn't necessary.

The case in which you need to call `AttachCurrentThread` is when `g_env` is NULL and `getEnvStat` is `JNI_EDETACHED`.

You also need to keep track of whether you did call `AttachCurrentThread`, since you should call `DetachCurrentThread` at some point in those cases. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026030/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-jnienv/30026231#30026231) for more info on that.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Yes, I got some things the wrong way obviously. I had seen the linked answer before, but clerly I didn't understand it well enough. One thing to point out though: Instead of the `JavaVMAttachArgs` I needed to pass NULL to `AttachCurrentThread` for it to work. This got copied in from somewhere and apparently is not needed here. Well, there is still a lot of reading to be done here for me. I'll add the working code to the question so it's clear what I changed